# AKKA persistent actor doesn't receive command messages in the receive command function

Tags: scala, jdbc, akka, akka-persistence

I am trying to use AKKA persistence together with the JDBC plugin. However, when experimenting with the persistent actors I face the problem that my persistent actor does not receive the messages it should receive.

Here is my application.conf file I use for the JDBC plugin.

```
akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG

  actor {
    #provider = cluster
  }

  persistence {
    journal.plugin = "jdbc-journal"
    snapshot-store.plugin = "jdbc-snapshot-store"
  }
}

  jdbc-journal {
  slick = ${slick}
}

# the akka-persistence-snapshot-store in use
jdbc-snapshot-store {
  slick = ${slick}
}

  jdbc-read-journal {
  slick = ${slick}
}

  slick {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource"
  db {
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource"
  driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_persistence"
  user = "root"
  password = ""
  numThreads = 5
  maxConnections = 5
  minConnections = 1
}
}
```

This is the code of my persistent actor (based on the AKKA documentation code)

```
case class Cmd(data: String)
case class Evt(data: String)

case class ExampleState(events: List[String] = Nil) {
  def updated(evt: Evt): ExampleState = copy(evt.data :: events)
  def size: Int = events.length
  override def toString: String = events.reverse.toString
}

class ExampleActor extends PersistentActor {
  override def persistenceId = "sample-id-1"

   var state = ExampleState()

  def updateState(event: Evt): Unit = {
    state = state.updated(event)
  }

  def numEvents =
    state.size

  override def receiveRecover: Receive = {
    case evt: Evt                                 => updateState(evt)
    case SnapshotOffer(_, snapshot: ExampleState) => state = snapshot
  }

  val snapShotInterval = 1000

  val receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case Cmd(data) => {
      println("in the command code block")
      persist(Evt(s"${data}-${numEvents}")) { event => {
        updateState(event)
        context.system.eventStream.publish(event)
        if (lastSequenceNr % snapShotInterval == 0 && lastSequenceNr != 0)
          saveSnapshot(state)
      }
      }
    }
    case "print"=>println(state)
  }
}
```

lastly, my test where I find the problem.

```
"The persistent actor" should {
    "Receive Command" in {
      val persistentActor = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor](),"persistentActorOne")
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      println("before the send")
      persistentActor ! Cmd("foo")
      persistentActor ! Cmd("bar")
      persistentActor ! Cmd("fizz")
      persistentActor ! Cmd("buzz")
      persistentActor ! "print"

      Thread.sleep(10000)
      println("after messages should be sent and received")
    }
  }
}
```

Can anybody see the reason why my persistent actor won't receive my messages/commands?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `override def receiveCommand: Receive = ...` instead of `val receiveCommand: Receive = ...`?

Comment: Unfortunatly, this gives the same result

Comment: Using inmemory persistence plugin this code works and prints:
`before the send`
`in the command code block`
`in the command code block`
`in the command code block`
`in the command code block`
`List(foo-0, bar-1, fizz-2, buzz-3)`
`after messages should be sent and received`

Comment: Yes, however, while using the jdbc plugin I do not receive messages at all so I don't see where I made the mistake.

Comment: Well you said you didn't get any commands received, so I assumed you didn't get any output from your print commands. but now It seems you're saying you do, but your persistence plugin doesn't work? What do you get on output? Anything? Did you try to run it not from test but from "main" and see if it works like this?

Comment: While using the jdbc plugin I get nothing as response(no prints from the receive command) just the trivial `before the send` and `after messages should be sent` messages since they are not part of the receiveCommand. I tried it in main but that gives the same result.